# SimpleXMLElement stops execution code

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, runtime-error

I have php function with the code in a loop,

```
$xml   = new SimpleXMLElement($request_url,null, TRUE);
```

The function run, in well upto end in localhost xampp but when upload it to server
It runs upto SimpleXMLElement, line and stops, not run upto the end of the function there

The error message is,

```
    Message: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http:/..."  
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
```

And my local php version is Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24
And my server version is PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Do you know any reason for this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function stop execution problem sloved, Used php sleep() function and try-catch block. Now with this flow it execute fine up to the end successfully.

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        ....
        ....
        $request_url = "the url";
    try{  
        sleep(1);
        $xml   = new SimpleXMLElement($request_url,null, TRUE);

      }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Skipped";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 503 Http header that is returned, suggests that the server on which the resource you're trying to load is not available.

This HTTP header 503 Service Unavailable means that:

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.

According to the W3 specification: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Can it be ram capasity problem ?

Comment: Can't it be php version problem ?

Comment: That's not very likely. It's not your script that doesn't work. It's the remote server from which you're trying to get the xml that gives the error. Your script just halts, because it cant process the xml.